# UICollectionViewCells appear empty while using JSONDecoder

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, jsondecoder

I am trying to use my decoded json data in a UICollectionView. The issue I'm having is that the cells are showing up blank.

When I print the for the results of the decoding using `print(playing)` or `print(searchs)` the console displays the proper json data. Problem is when I turn it into `var = nowPlaying = [Results]()` nothing is printed to the console except `[]`.

If I try using `var nowPlaying = [NowPlaying]()` I receive the error `Value of type 'FilmsViewController.NowPlaying' has no member title` as `let title = film.title` and the console only shows `[]`

What I'm trying to solve is how to display the data within the UICollectionView.

Code:

```
import UIKit
import AFNetworking


class FilmsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, 
UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, 
UISearchBarDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

var nowPlaying = [Results]()

struct NowPlaying: Codable {
    let results: [Results]
}

struct Results: Codable {
    let title: String
    let poster_path: String?
    let id: Int
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.filmsCollection.dataSource = self
    self.filmsCollection.delegate = self

    newFilms()

    print(nowPlaying)
    print(nowPlaying.count)


}

func collectionView(_ _collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if searchBar.text != "" {
        return searchTitle.count
    } else {
        return nowPlaying.count
    }
}


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = filmsCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "filmCell", for: indexPath) as! FilmCell

        if searchBar.text == "" {
            let film = nowPlaying[indexPath.row]
            let title = film.title
            let poster = film.poster_path
            let baseUrl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"
            let imageUrl = URL(string: baseUrl + poster!)
            cell.titleLabel.text = title
            cell.posterImage.setImageWith(imageUrl!)
        }

        return cell


}

   ////////Parse Film API//////////////////


    func newFilms() {

        let apiKey = ""
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=\(apiKey)&language=en-US&page=1")
        let request = URLRequest(
            url: url! as URL,
            cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,
            timeoutInterval: 10 )

        let session = URLSession (
            configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
            delegate: nil,
            delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main
        )

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let playing = [try! JSONDecoder().decode(NowPlaying.self, from: data)]
                    print(playing)
                    self.filmsCollection.reloadData()

                }

            }

            self.filmsCollection.reloadData()

        })


        task.resume()

    }

    //////////End Parse Film API///////////////////
```

JSON Api Data:

```
{
results: [
{
vote_count: 549,
id: 335983,
video: false,
vote_average: 6.7,
title: "Venom",
popularity: 692.629,
poster_path: "/2uNW4WbgBXL25BAbXGLnLqX71Sw.jpg",
original_language: "en",
original_title: "Venom",
genre_ids: [
27,
878,
28,
53
],
backdrop_path: "/VuukZLgaCrho2Ar8Scl9HtV3yD.jpg",
adult: false,
overview: "When Eddie Brock acquires the powers of a symbiote, he will have to 
release his alter-ego “Venom” to save his life.",
release_date: "2018-10-03"
},
{
vote_count: 2515,
id: 363088,
video: false,
vote_average: 6.9,
title: "Ant-Man and the Wasp",
popularity: 247.334,
poster_path: "/rv1AWImgx386ULjcf62VYaW8zSt.jpg",
original_language: "en",
original_title: "Ant-Man and the Wasp",
genre_ids: [
28,
12,
35,
878,
10751,
10749
],
backdrop_path: "/6P3c80EOm7BodndGBUAJHHsHKrp.jpg",
adult: false,
overview: "Just when his time under house arrest is about to end, Scott Lang 
puts again his freedom at risk to help Hope van Dyne and Dr. Hank Pym dive into 
the quantum realm and try to accomplish, against time and any chance of 
success, a very dangerous rescue mission.",
release_date: "2018-07-04"
},
```

Comment: Where are you decoding NowPlaying. Please post the json data also

Comment: Might want to take our API key out of your question.

Comment: You should share parsing code. Also, in the mentioned error you are calling `title` on `NowPlaying`. `title` is a member of `Results` not `NowPlaying `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the data in `var nowPlaying = [Results]()` in a wrong way.

Either you can go like this:

```
let playing = try! JSONDecoder().decode(NowPlaying.self, from: data)
print(playing)
self.nowPlaying = playing.results
self.filmsCollection.reloadData()
```

and the data will be populated in the `array`.

Or you can go like this :

```
var nowPlaying : NowPlaying!
```

and in api method :

```
self.nowPlaying = try! JSONDecoder().decode(NowPlaying.self, from: data)
self.filmsCollection.reloadData()
```

then in `cellForItemAt`:

```
let film = nowPlaying.results[indexPath.row]
```

I haven't compiled the code and I also don't know the json data. But I am giving the solution according to what I understood from the question.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: When using either method I get the error `Value of type '[FilmsViewController.NowPlaying]' has no member results`. I have updated my question with an example of the JSON

Comment: I removed the `[]` from the decoder and it works. Thanks!